# Call function with argument Object& in c++

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to hand over to a function a pointer to an object and then work with this in the function. However this somehow does not work. Please excuse if my nomenclature is not correct. I haven't worked with c++ for a while. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <fstream>

class Grid {
public:
  std::array<std::array<std::array<double,10>, 10>, 10> chi;
  Grid();
};

Grid::Grid()
{
  std::array<std::array<std::array<double,10>, 10>, 10> chi={};  
}

void set_initial_conditions(Grid& g);

int main () {
  Grid g();// greate object
  set_initial_conditions(g);// set the initial conditions.  
  return 0;
}

void set_initial_conditions(Grid& g) {
  std::cout<<"set initial conditions"<<std::endl;
}
```

When compiling with

```
c++ -o minimal_example minimal_example.cpp -std=c++17
```

I get the following error message:

```
minimal_example.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
minimal_example.cpp:22:26: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘Grid&’ from expression of type ‘Grid()’
   22 |   set_initial_conditions(g);
      |                          ^
minimal_example.cpp:18:35: note: in passing argument 1 of ‘void set_initial_conditions(Grid&)’
   18 | void set_initial_conditions(Grid& g);
      |                             ~~~~~~^
```

Comment: `std::array<std::array<std::array<double,10>, 10>, 10> chi={};` this line in your default constructor shadows the member variable instead of initializing it. You can just leave the default constructor blank. As for the actual question, looks like the most vexing parse. Replace `Grid g();` with `Grid g;` or `Grid g{};`.

Comment: This particular anomaly trips up so many folks (beginners and experienced devs alike) that it has its own name. The relevant search term is "most vexing parse".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```cpp
// Create object.
Grid g;
```

Instead of:

```cpp
Grid g();// create object
```

Or even something like:

```cpp
Grid *g = new Grid(); // Heap allocation.
set_initial_conditions(*g);

delete g; // Later manual memory release.
```

---

**Edit** -- also replace your constructor's line:

```
std::array<std::array<std::array<double,10>, 10>, 10> chi={};
```

With something like:

```
this->chi = {};
```

> **Note** that many languages don't need you to write `this` explicitly, but recommend it to prevent conflicts.

Comment: It's not related to compiler optimizations, it's the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). The compiler is interpreting `Grid g();` as the declaration of a function, `g`, which takes no arguments and returns a `Grid`.

Comment: You are right, normal types don't have parenthesis (but the error says `type ‘Grid()’`), so, it really is treated as a function declaration.